# Fancybox images loaded with ajax

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have a `<select>` and each options load a image into a div. The output of the ajax image loader is

```
<a class="fancybox" href="/useruploads/types/4.jpg" title="Columnlist #1">
    <img style="max-width:300px" src="/useruploads/types/4.jpg" alt="Columnlist #1">
</a>
<h6>Columnlist #1</h6>
```

And this gets inserted into a `<div class="thumbnail"></div>`

So I tried with the following javascript

```
$('body').delegate('a.fancybox', 'click', function() {
    $(this).fancybox();
    console.log($(this));
    return false;
});
```

And the this logs the `<a>` element, but the image does not gets fancyboxes (When I remove the return false, the url for the  loads)

I have added jquery (1.9.1), fancybox javascript (2.1.5) and fancybox css, and all files loads fine into the browser.

No errors in the console.

[EDIT]
I have changed to Highslide and now it works perfect

Comment: if you are using fancybox v2.1.5 then you don't need `.delegate()` or `.on()` just bind the selector `.fancybox` to fancybox normally and it will work for any present or future (ajax added) elements.

Answer (score 0):

> As of jQuery 1.7, [**.delegate()**](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) has been superseded by the .on() method.
>   For earlier versions, however, it remains the most effective means to
>   use event delegation.

Use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Syntax

```
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```

Your code become

```
$('body').on('click','a.fancybox' ,function() {
    $(this).fancybox();
    console.log($(this));
    return false;
});
```

Comment: @Martin is your site live ?

Comment: fancybox v2.1.5 doesn't need `.delegate()` or `.on()` either.